# Removing/hiding min/max/close buttons after runtime

Tags: winapi, windows-10

I have a window, well my friend does and I'm trying to help him.

He wants to make the min/max/close buttons draggable. So he made his buttons and now wants to hide the native ones.

So we used this code:

```
int style;
 style = GetWindowLong(GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_STYLE); 
 style &= ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX; 
 SetWindowLong(GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_STYLE, style);
```

This hides the min and max. Any ideas on how to hide the close?

Comment: This sounds like the wrong solution. You should take over painting the non-client area.

Comment: Thanks much @DavidHeffernan for always quick replies! Can you please point me in direction of code for such a thing.

Comment: Firefox or Chome source code would be an obvious place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `WS_SYSMENU` flag to hide the close button.

Comment: Thanks very much @William for this! I will test out and report how it works out :)